# What does "junta" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

I know "junta" in Spanish means meeting. However, what does "junta" mean in the following sentence? Is it correctly used? This from a document I am translating into English. It may contain mistakes.

> Dos tapas de toallas húmedo se pusieron en una bolsa plástica desechable, con una línea grapada a 1/3 del fondo de la bolsa para mantener la toallla de papel en su lugar y para proporcionar una **junta** para mantener las semillas de rábano.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but the Spanish text sample stinks. For starters, _"toallas humedo"_ is a concordance error, the composition is clumsy and it's poorly punctuated. I don't envy you if you have to work with this kind of texts.

Comment: @deStrangis it actually seems that it's already a translation, probably from an online service :D

Comment: I agree the document is poorly written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "joint" (as in "union" or "junction"), the place where two things join each other.

See the 4th definition [here](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/junta).